# Recording user actions events in browser using java

Tags: java, events, browser

In browser(Firefox or Chrome) user performs many actions such as filling input or pressing submit button etc. Is there anyway(in Java) where we can record these actions(which component he clicks or Xpath of that element) on client side?  Selenium has Webdriver but i am unable to find if it can does this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a Java library called [JSFlight](https://github.com/d0k1/jsflight).

This tool is splitted into three main parts:

- Recorder - it's the set of the javascript files, that you should insert into your html document. You can configure which types of events you want to track. It can work with iframes too.
- Player - this is the main program/library which plays recorded events.
- Server - it's the wrapper upon the Player. Starts a standalone server with rest api. Uses the MongoDB.